# Binding centerX property doesn't work

Tags: properties, javafx, java-8

I'm learning new features of Java 8 with the book **Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient**

On the pages 76 and 77 the author says:

> We always want the circle centered in the scene.
>
> ...
>
> When the scene width changes, so does
> that property. All that remains is to bind that computed property to
> the circle’s `centerX` property:
>
> ```
> circle.centerXProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(scene.widthProperty(),
> ```
>
> 2));

As there was no complete runnable sample I created my own. Here is it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Exercise0404 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Circle circle = new Circle(50);
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(circle);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(2));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Hello");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

But if I run the code and resize the scene the circle doesn't move to the center. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting your circle in a `FlowPane` which in charge of the layout.

When you use absolute positioning, prefer the use of an adequate pane:  [javafx.scene.layout.Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html). From `Pane` javadoc:

> This class may be used directly in cases where absolute positioning of children is required since it does not perform layout beyond resizing resizable children to their preferred sizes.

---

You just have to change the `FlowPane` to a `Pane` and it will work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Exercise0404 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Circle circle = new Circle(50);
        Pane pane = new Pane(circle);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(2));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Hello");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```